# How do I generate lft and rght values for a cakephp 2.0 tree?

Tags: cakephp, tree, cakephp-2.0

I've read that if you have a model that `$actsAs = array('Tree')`, that you can simply set the `parent_id` for your seed data, and a call to `$this->Model->recover()` should generate the proper `lft` and `rght` values for you, but when I do this, Cake seems to generate random values every time. The values vary from very large (in the thousands) to negative values. I've checked for circular references and found none as well. What could be wrong here?

SQL:

```
create table menus (
   id        int auto_increment not null,
   parent_id int                null    ,
   lft       int                null    ,
   rght      int                null    ,
   title     varchar(1024)      not null,
   path      varchar(1024)      not null,
   constraint pk_menus primary key (id)
)   ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

This is the seeded data:          After one Model->recover()
+----+-----------+------+------+  +----+-----------+------+------+
| id | parent_id | lft  | rght |  | id | parent_id | lft  | rght |
+----+-----------+------+------+  +----+-----------+------+------+
|  1 |      NULL | NULL | NULL |  |  1 |      NULL |  595 |  619 |
|  7 |         1 | NULL | NULL |  |  7 |         1 |  619 |  567 |
|  6 |         1 | NULL | NULL |  |  6 |         1 |  627 |  595 |
|  5 |         1 | NULL | NULL |  |  5 |         1 |  600 |  621 |
|  4 |         1 | NULL | NULL |  |  4 |         1 |  603 |  621 |
|  3 |         1 | NULL | NULL |  |  3 |         1 |  619 |  529 |
|  2 |         1 | NULL | NULL |  |  2 |         1 |  595 |  529 |
|  8 |         2 | NULL | NULL |  |  8 |         2 |  627 |  628 |
| 13 |         3 | NULL | NULL |  | 13 |         3 |  595 |  567 |
| 12 |         3 | NULL | NULL |  | 12 |         3 |  627 |  621 |
| 11 |         3 | NULL | NULL |  | 11 |         3 |  595 |  631 |
| 10 |         3 | NULL | NULL |  | 10 |         3 |  604 |  529 |
|  9 |         3 | NULL | NULL |  |  9 |         3 |  595 |  567 |
| 14 |         5 | NULL | NULL |  | 14 |         5 |  628 |  629 |
| 15 |         5 | NULL | NULL |  | 15 |         5 |  567 |  529 |
| 16 |         5 | NULL | NULL |  | 16 |         5 |  619 |  600 |
| 17 |         5 | NULL | NULL |  | 17 |         5 |  627 |  605 |
| 21 |         6 | NULL | NULL |  | 21 |         6 |  567 |  619 |
| 20 |         6 | NULL | NULL |  | 20 |         6 |  595 |  567 |
| 19 |         6 | NULL | NULL |  | 19 |         6 |  619 |  600 |
| 18 |         6 | NULL | NULL |  | 18 |         6 |  567 |  529 |
| 22 |        10 | NULL | NULL |  | 22 |        10 |  567 |  619 |
| 23 |        11 | NULL | NULL |  | 23 |        11 |   64 |  621 |
| 24 |        12 | NULL | NULL |  | 24 |        12 |  627 |  621 |
| 25 |        13 | NULL | NULL |  | 25 |        13 |  605 |  595 |
| 32 |        16 | NULL | NULL |  | 32 |        16 |  628 |  627 |
| 31 |        16 | NULL | NULL |  | 31 |        16 |  567 |  619 |
| 30 |        16 | NULL | NULL |  | 30 |        16 |   64 |  621 |
| 29 |        16 | NULL | NULL |  | 29 |        16 |  567 |  619 |
| 28 |        16 | NULL | NULL |  | 28 |        16 |  595 |  567 |
| 27 |        16 | NULL | NULL |  | 27 |        16 |  627 |  621 |
| 26 |        16 | NULL | NULL |  | 26 |        16 |  605 |  595 |
| 33 |        17 | NULL | NULL |  | 33 |        17 |  567 |  619 |
| 37 |        19 | NULL | NULL |  | 37 |        19 |   52 |  619 |
| 36 |        19 | NULL | NULL |  | 36 |        19 |   52 |  619 |
| 35 |        19 | NULL | NULL |  | 35 |        19 |  595 |  619 |
| 34 |        19 | NULL | NULL |  | 34 |        19 |   63 |  621 |
| 38 |        20 | NULL | NULL |  | 38 |        20 |   63 |  621 |
| 39 |        20 | NULL | NULL |  | 39 |        20 |   63 |  621 |
| 40 |        21 | NULL | NULL |  | 40 |        21 |  605 |  595 |
+----+-----------+------+------+  +----+-----------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I set the `lft` and `rght` values of the top level item to `1` and `2` respectively, `recover()` now generates the rest of the values properly. I find this to be a bug, but not a terrible one.

Comment: Where you found that? can you provide me the link to the article? thanks ;)