# How do I generate correct lft and rght values for a cakephp Tree?

Tags: cakephp, tree

I'm using a cakephp recover() function to set up the lft and rght but when execute the function recover the same larger values are put in this two columns.

Eg.

before run Tree::recover('parent');

```
+------+------+
| lft  | rght |
+------+------+
|37600 | 42875|
+------+------+
```

after run Tree::recover('parent');

```
+-----------+-----------+
|    lft    |    rght   |
+-----------+-----------+
|2147483647 | 2147483647|
+-----------+-----------+
```

Why this happened? also I'm trying to put all values (lft and rght) to "0" or "null" but this happens [How do I generate lft and rght values for a cakephp 2.0 tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496084/how-do-i-generate-lft-and-rght-values-for-a-cakephp-2-0-tree) 
(a random negative numbers are generated by recover function).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps and i know this question is old but 2147483647 is the largest value for a 32-bit signed integer ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647)). Thus, i think you are trying to store a number larger than that in your `lft` and `rght` fields. As to why this is happening I'm not sure.